# How can I switch my code from UnityScript to C# (csharp)?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

This script(code) it works fine in UnityScript, but now i want to switch it to C#. This is what I've got so far. I think there is a problem at "transform.position" and generating a "random position" for my character.
Probably it's very simple thing, but I'm a beginner in C#, so please help me out.

```
public class AntScript : MonoBehaviour 
{
    public GameObject ant;
    public GameObject scoreText;
    public GameObject livesText;
    public double walkingSpeed = 0.0f;
    public int livesNumber = 3;
    public int scoreNumber = 0;
    float x;
    float y;

    void Start() {   ant = GameObject.Find("Ant");
        scoreText = GameObject.Find("Score");
        livesText = GameObject.Find("Lives");

        //Initialize the GUI components
        livesText.GetComponent<Text>().text = "Lives Remaining: " + livesNumber;
        scoreText.GetComponent<Text>().text = "Score: " + scoreNumber;

        //Place the ant in a random position on start of the game
        ant.transform.position.x = generateX();
        ant.transform.position.y = generateY();
    }

    void Update()
    {
        Vector3 p = transform.position;

        if (ant.transform.position.y < -4.35 && livesNumber > 0)
        {

            livesNumber -= 1;
            livesText.GetComponent<Text>().text = "Lives Remaining: " + livesNumber;
            generateCoordinates();

        }
        else if (ant.transform.position.y < -4.35 && livesNumber == 0)
        {
            Destroy(GameObject.Find("Ant"));
            gameOver();

        }
        else
        {
            ant.transform.position.y -= walkingSpeed;
        }
    }

    void gameOver()
    {
        Application.LoadLevel("GameOver");
    }


    //Generates random x
    void generateX()
    {
        x = Random.Range(-2.54f, 2.54f);
        //return x;
    }

    //Generates random y
    void generateY()
    {
        y = Random.Range(-4.0f, 3.8f);
        //return y;
    }

    //Move the "Ant" to the new coordiantess
    void generateCoordinates()
    {
        //You clicked it!
        scoreNumber += 1;

        //Update the score display
        scoreText.GetComponent<Text>().text = "Score: " + scoreNumber;
        ant.transform.position.x = generateX();
        ant.transform.position.y = generateY();
    }

    //If tapped or clicked
    void OnMouseDown()
    {
        //Place the ant at another point
        generateCoordinates();

        //Increase the walking speed by 0.01
        walkingSpeed += 0.01f;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is indeed a quirk of C#, it took me a while to get it at first

The problem is, transform.position is not a field, its a setter/getter (its a pair of methods internally, imagine it as Vector3 GetPosition() and SetPosition(Vector3), wchich means you need to pass a whole struct into it, you cannot just set x or y (as the method cannot be called until you have all the parameters.
The workaround is really simple fortunately

```
Vector3 temp = ant.transform.position; // use a getter
temp.x = generateX();                  // modify a struct
temp.y = generateY();
ant.transform.position=temp;           // use a setter
```

Comment: Okay, but now i have problems with generateX() and Y()..."Cannot implicity convert type 'void' to 'float'. " and in another places this temp variable is not solving the problem already... I'm realy bad sry ... :D

Comment: because you dont return y and your generateX and generateY are marked void as non returning. Rather than class level variables, they were trying to get you to return a variable from the method

Comment: @soosistvan you have return statements within your methods, just uncomment them (and change return type from void to float)

Comment: You could then reduce it to one line again using `transform.position = new Vector3(generateX(), generateY(), transform.position.z);` or in case of a 2D app simply `new Vector2(generateX(), generateY())`